# Asp.Net MVC4 assign a supplier to aspNet UserId

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC5 application in which I have a requirement for an admin to assign suppliers to their ASP.NET user Id login details. This is because a supplier could register to my application which would contain a different ID to the one that has already been setup. I need an admin to get their supplier ID and assign it to their ASP.Net user id.

I created the suppliers and users into a dropdown lists which is all well. I now need to update the supplier ID to match the ASP.Net user ID

What I have is as follows 
Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AssignSupplier(string supplierName, string UserName )
    {
        ApplicationUser user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();


        UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
        new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

      //  this.UserManager.ad

        var supp = db.Suppliers.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Suppliers = supp;
        var users = db.Users.OrderBy(r => r.UserName).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.UserName.ToString(), Text = rr.UserName }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Users = users;

        return View("ManageUserRoles");
    }
```

I am not sure on how I save the AspNet user Id back into the suppliers table and overwrite the current ID, can this be done at all. I have used a very similar solution to assign users to roles by following http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc

I wondered if anybody could help or advise

Many thanks 
Mark

Comment: why you are not using roles

Comment: What are you want to achieve by doing this? If you want to associate a user with a supplier, you rather specify the relation the other way around by setting a SupplierID on the user.

Comment: thanks @Richard Mosseveld this is what I have now done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to create a one-to-many relation between `Supplier` and `User`?

Your `User` would need a `Supplier`:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    //...
    public virtual Supplier Supplier {get;set;}
    //...
}
```

and your `Supplier` needs a list of `User`

```
public class Supplier
{
    //...
    public virtual List<ApplicationUser> Users {get;set;}
    //...
}
```

Then in your controller you assign the supplier to the user:

```
public ActionResult AssignSupplier(string supplierName, string UserName )
{
    ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == UserName);

    Supplier supplier = db.Suppliers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == supplierName);

    // Assign supplier to user
    user.Supplier = supplier;

    // Save
    db.SaveChanges();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ahhh ok thanks @Chris this might be what I am missing . I will give this a go thanks for the heads up :)